# Индекс находился вне границы массива (C++)

Tags: c++-cli, arraylist

Надо считать данные с файла и записать их в таблицу (dataGridView). Проблема в том когда я выбираю файл у меня выскакивает окно Индекс находился вне границы массива.Код

```
if(dataGridView->RowCount)
{
     System::Windows::Forms::DialogResult dialogResult = MessageBox::Show("Зберегти дані", "Увага!!!", MessageBoxButtons::YesNo);
     if(dialogResult == System::Windows::Forms::DialogResult::Yes)
     {
         if (path == nullptr){
             if (saveFileDialog->ShowDialog() == System::Windows::Forms::DialogResult::OK)
             {
             Stream^ paths;
             if ((paths = saveFileDialog->OpenFile()) != nullptr)
             {
             path = saveFileDialog->InitialDirectory + saveFileDialog->FileName;
             paths->Close();
             saveFile(path);
             }
             }
     }
     else saveFile(path);
     }
 }

 if (openFileDialog->ShowDialog() == System::Windows::Forms::DialogResult::OK)
 {
     Stream^ paths;
     if ((paths = openFileDialog->OpenFile()) != nullptr)
 {
         path = openFileDialog->InitialDirectory + openFileDialog->FileName;
         StreamReader^ myread = gcnew StreamReader(paths);
         array<String^>^ str;
         int num = 0;
         array<String^>^ arr = myread->ReadToEnd()->Split('\n');
         dataGridView->RowCount = num = arr->Length-1;
         for (int i = 0; i < num; i++)
{
         str = arr[i]->Split(':');
         for (int j = 0; j < dataGridView->ColumnCount; j++)
         dataGridView->Rows[i]->Cells[j]->Value = str[j];
     }
             myread->Close();
     }
 }
```

Компилятор матерится на эту строку

```
dataGridView->Rows[i]->Cells[j]->Value = str[j];`
```

Comment: Предположительно дело может быть в том, что у вас цикл от нуля до ColumnCount, а должен ведь быть до (ColumnCount - 1)... Попробуйте исправить это место, и отпишитесь - помогло или нет :) P.S. Возможно, для i тоже надо будет сделать (num - 1).

Comment: @SergeyPopov Спасибо за помощь, но уже не надо. Оно само заработало при том что я не менял код. Магия!!!

Comment: Не за что. Но я бы рекомендовал Вам всё же отладить код, т.к. проблема может повториться снова, т.к. у Вас в коде достаточно "классический" выход за границы массива всё-таки...

Comment: Тот вариант что вы предложили не работает. Если я задам ColumnCount - 1 то у меня данные вставляются только в 1 колонку, а их у меня 2

Comment: Всё, прошу прощения - это я туплю что-то. Нельзя в выходные на работу выходить :-D Вы правы, у вас сравнение идёт "меньше", а не "меньше или равно", так что всё должно быть корректно. Интересно, конечно, откуда изначальная ошибка появлялась...

Comment: Уже не работает